# Android - using a keyboard in a webview with adverts

Tags: android, webview, admob

I've added adverts into my webview application. The problem is whenever someone tries to type something into somewhere inside the webview then the view becomes only half shown.

[image]

Above is this being shown. (The second image is smaller because the keyboard was cut out of the screenshot)

This only happens whilst having adverts in the application.
I found that if I put the webview behind the adview then it's fine, but that's a problem because then some of the webview is hidden behind an adview.

Any ideas? Could it be a manifest configuration doing this?

Big thanks to all help in advance.

Comment: Truly stuck with this, nothing on google I find either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to the link below I got it fixed.I had to stop the keyboard pushing the adview up and re-sizing everything. To do this, I added

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to the activity tag in the manifest.

https://github.com/Android-LayerCake/AdMobWrapper/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml